# How to generate email able report after every test is completed in TestNG?

Tags: selenium, testng

How to generate email able report after every test is completed in TestNG?

My use case- in my testng.xml file i have 2 tests.
1st test will run the login as a example.
2nd test is for logout as a example.

in my testng.xml file i use 2 test to run these two. but i need the emailable report after every test is completed. is that possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the appropriate listener and implement your business logic (sending email in your case)

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-listeners